# How to use reverse interpolation pug.js

Tags: javascript, pug, string-interpolation

I have a pug.js that has a good amount of code included in it. In order to write the block of code I have to write

```js
pre #[code.language-python print("Hello!")]
```

I know that I can write a variable and use it like this:

```js
- var codeMsg = 'Hello!'

h1 #{codeMsg}
```

but is there a way to use it so that I write a variable that contains the long tag declaration, and then put in my code? Like this:

```js
myNewTag print("Hello!")
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine a [mixin](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html) with [tag interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#tag-interpolation) like this:

```
// mixin declaration
mixin python
  pre
    code.language-python
      block

// usage (don't forget the trailing dot)
+python.
  print("Hello, World!")
  print("Goodbye, World!")
```

Comment: Hm. This is great. is there any way to use this inline?